# How to use POST to set the results of a SurveyJS survey?

Tags: surveyjs

Is it possible to use POST to set the results of a SurveyJS survey?

I can use GET to get the survey results, but I am struggling with setting.

Here is the code I use to GET the results:

```
urlToSurvey = "https://dxsurvey.com/api/MySurveys/getSurveyResults/surveyID?accessKey=myKey";

$.get(urlToSurvey, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

I want to use SurveyJS to store students' progress in an open-source plugin (Adapt Learning), so I want to directly post the progress data to SurveyJS as I cannot run a stand-alone html in the plugin.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this file - https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs/blob/master/src/dxSurveyService.ts

Here is the code responsible for sending the result:

```
  public sendResult(
    postId: string,
    result: JSON,
    onSendResult: (success: boolean, response: any) => void,
    clientId: string = null,
    isPartialCompleted: boolean = false
  ) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", dxSurveyService.serviceUrl + "/post/");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    var data = { postId: postId, surveyResult: JSON.stringify(result) };
    if (clientId) data["clientId"] = clientId;
    if (isPartialCompleted) data["isPartialCompleted"] = true;
    var dataStringify: string = JSON.stringify(data);
    var self = this;
    xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
      if (!onSendResult) return;
      onSendResult(xhr.status == 200, xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.send(dataStringify);
  }
```

The required params are the postId and result json. You can get your postId from the MySurveys page of the service (https://surveyjs.io/Service/MySurveys/ note that MySurveys page requires authorization).

This is a TypeScript code, but I'm sure it can easily be converted to the JS.